# Binary operator overloading in templates to only accept certain other templates, handling different argument sets correctly

Tags: templates, operator-overloading, d

I'm learning myself some D and wanted to implement a set of templates that safely handles physical values (i.e. values with units).
The final goal would be to be able to do something like this:

```
int main(string[] argv){
    auto m1 = meter!float(1.0);
    auto m2 = meter!double(2.0);
    // m3 should be meter!double with value 3
    auto m3 = m1 + m2;

    auto f1 = feet!float(1.0);
    auto f2 = feet!int(2);
    // where f3 should be of type feet!float with value 3
    auto f3 = f1 + f2;

    // and finally, where m4 should be meter!double
    // with value 1.33 (i.e. correctly converted addition of the feet value)
    auto m4 = m1 + f1
}
```

however, at the moment I can't even get the additon operator for a simple meter!float + meter!float to work. It interestingly fails the same way with meter!double and even (in a modified version) with a simple float. This indicates to me, that I'm either missing something fundamental or trying to do something that is impossible to do trivially.
I looked at  github.com/PhilippeSigaud/D-templates-tutorial, Dlang.org and www.ddili.org/ders/d.en/ and google for 2h now, but couldn't find any solution.

Here are my templates (please note that I left out the isNumeric assertions and similar for the sake of readability)

```
class Length(ValueT)
{
   ValueT value;
   string name;
   string symbol;

   this(ValueT value, string name, string symbol)
   {
        this.value = value;
        this.value = name;
        this.symbol = symbol;
   }
}

class meter(ValueT):Length!(ValueT)
{
    this(ValueT value){
        super(value, "meter", "m");
    }

    // Try 1:
    // the first try for overloading the op
    ref opBinary(string op, otherValueT) (in meter!(otherValueT) rhs)
    if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "%" || op == "^^")
    {
        mixin("alias typeof(this.value" ~ op ~ "rhs.value) ReturnT;
              return meter!ReturnT(this.value" ~ op ~ "rhs.value);");    
    }
    // output:
    // Error: no property 'opCall' for type 'units.meter!float.meter'
    // Error: template instance units.meter!float.meter.opBinary!("+", float)
    //        error instantiating

    // Try 2:
    // I also tried this:
    ref opBinary(string op, Rhs:meter!(otherValueT)) (in Rhs rhs)
    if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "%" || op == "^^")
    {
        mixin("alias typeof(this.value" ~ op ~ "rhs.value) ReturnT;
              return meter!ReturnT(this.value" ~ op ~ "rhs.value);");    
    }
    // output:
    //Error: undefined identifier otherValueT, obviously

    // Try3:
    // and finally this, to see if using a templated something on the right hand side
    // was causing the problem, passing just a float (ie auto m3 = m1 + 1.0;
    ref opBinary(string op, otherValueT) (in otherValueT rhs)
    if (op == "+" || op == "-" || op == "/" || op == "%" || op == "^^")
    {
        mixin("alias typeof(this.value" ~ op ~ "rhs) ReturnT;
              return meter!ReturnT(this.value" ~ op ~ "rhs);");    
    }
    // output:
    // Error: no property 'opCall' for type 'units.meter!float.meter'
    // Error: template instance units.meter!float.meter.opBinary!("+", float)
    //        error instantiating
}
```

So my questions are:

1. Is something like my imagined endgoal accomplishable with D's templates?
2. If so, how could it be done?
3. Is template specialisation the way to go (for the meters and feet part of the problem)?
4. How do I specify that my operator expects an instantiation of (the same/a specific) template, but wit probably different instation arguements?
5. Is it possible to overload the operator to achive polymorphistic behaviour that is yet typesafe and predictable?

As I said, I'm new to D and relatively new to templates in general. So any kind of illuminating answer or reading hint would be appreciated. If you need clarification on details, post a comment and I'll try my best.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, there's a lot of things to talk about here. Let's get started with this line:

```
auto m1 = meter!float(1.0);
```

That won't work because meter is a class. Classes in D always have to be newed*. That's why it says no opCall: Class(x) without new tries to call a static opCall method and there are none here. To call the constructor on a class, you need to use the new operator.

Structs are different, they don't have to be newed. For this kind of thing, structs are better than classes (indeed, I think in D structs are the better choice unless you specifically need interfaces and virtual function).

- well, you can also placement construct them without new, but that's an advanced topic.

Next, don't return ref on your opBinary. You can't return a new thing by ref, only member variables. So take ref off and replace it with auto... and then your first try will compile.

For try 2, you want to only accept a specialization of meter. You were very close, just have to add the otherValueT to the list:

```
auto opBinary(string op, Rhs : meter!(otherValueT), otherValueT) (in Rhs rhs)
```

(and add the new when you make the meter and change ref to auto). This is documented here under the header Argument Deduction: http://dlang.org/template.html The example they use is of an array, but it works for templates too. You can also read more here http://dlang.org/expression.html#IsExpression see form #7 - the is expression and template matching work the same way.

Rhs will now only be instantiations of meter, with the type given as otherValueT. You can do operations on these (add, etc.) or you can do static if on the is expressions to change the type yourself. These checks are a way you can get the polymorphic behavior you want.

Lastly, I would use structs here instead of classes. Here's how I would do it (well, not quite, we can make it more generic and make meters, feet, etc. one line things with mixin templates, but here's the start):

```
/// A length represented as a single type (we'll use centimeters here)
/// This is analogous to your base class.
struct Length(T) {
    /// don't want people to construct this directly
    private this(T t) { value = t; }

    T value;
}

/// The length with a particular unit. feet can be done the same way.
/// this is analogous to the specialized child class.
struct meters(T) {
    /// the actual value stored as the generic base type
    private Length!T value;

    /// we can get it for conversions. Doing a getter because we do not
    /// want this to be assignable to directly (though it could be i guess)
    Length!T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    /// this allows implicit conversion to Length!T via the property
    alias getValue this;

    /// construct with the basic type, int, float, whatever
    this(T t) {
        value.value = t * 100; // 100 centimeters per meter
    }

    /// construct with an existing length value (no conversion needed)
    this(Length!T t) {
         value = t;
    }

    /// just for displaying it with some details
    string toString() {
        import std.string;
        // again, converting the store - centimeters - back to the
        // display type - meters - for printing
        return format("%0.2f meters (stored as %s)", value.value / 100, T.stringof);
    }

    /// this works with the base type: Length!T. Saves us from reimplementing
    /// it over and over again for meters, feet, etc., while still keeping
    /// strict type rules intact.
    auto opBinary(string op, LengthType : Length!T, T)(LengthType rhs) {
        // I'm using a helper function to get the type instead of the alias
        // and mixin you did just because I think this is a bit more readable
        auto helper() {
            auto a = mixin("value.value " ~ op ~ " rhs.value");
            // since we're working with converted values already, we
            // explicitly construct the length type to avoid double convesion
            return meters!(typeof(a))(Length!(typeof(a))(a));
        }
        return helper();
    }

    /// but since opBinary is a fairly strict template, it won't do the implicit
    /// conversions via alias this! We'll enable that here for convenience
    auto opBinary(string op, T)(T rhs) if(isALength!T) {
        return opBinary!op(rhs.value); // just forward to the other function
    }
}

/// helper for checking the alias this (base type) of our type. Can we
/// automatically convert the given value to a Length!T ?
bool isALength(T)() {
    enum aliasThis = __traits(getAliasThis, T);
    static if(aliasThis.length == 0) {
        // no alias this base type at all, definitely not one
        return false;
    } else {
        /// aliasThis returns a list of members, so we check the first one
        /// and since we decided to make our alias this a getter function, we
        /// also go ahead and call it here to inspect the return value.
        static if(is(typeof(__traits(getMember, T, aliasThis)()) : Length!T, T))
            return true;
        else {
            /// has alias this but is of the wrong type
            return false;
        }
    }
}

void main() {
    auto l = meters!int(1);
    auto l2 = meters!float(0.12);

    import std.stdio;
    writeln(l + l2); // 1 meter + 0.12 meters = 1.12 meters, int + float = float.
}
```

So you were pretty close, just a few little errors to make it compile and then the class -> struct change makes it more efficient and more intuitive. A class would be a reference object too so assigning to one would change others. With the struct, it is a value just like int or float.

Comment: Wow, now that's what I call an answer! Thank you very much, you have in deed illuminated me! (I'd upvote it twice if I could)

Comment: BTW I kept playing for a few more minutes: http://arsdnet.net/dcode/inches.d there you can see me playing with mixin templates (it is basically the body of meters here, but with the constants factored out as parameters) and adding the cast operator, decomposing the template type in there. Some of these is(foo : a!b, alias a, b) is some weird, uncommon syntax, but once you've done it a couple times, the pattern isn't that bad. If you play with that code, observe the loss of data with inches!int as a store. It cuts off half a centimeter! The last line can change from float to int to see it.

Comment: May I say, that this was exactly the next step I had in mind? Thanks for the link, I'll study it now.

Comment: cool :) Note too that the getAliasThis thing I used in the longer code is a bleeding edge feature - just added in the newest release of dmd last month. If you are on an older compiler, you can skip that part and just check if the .value property exists at all by simply trying to use it. I just wanted to check the type in as much detail as possible here. If you have more questions about a specific part or want to move on, feel free to ask them too, I kinda dumped some code on you here lol

Comment: Hm, time for a compiler update I guess. Thanks for dumping, you kicked approx. a lightyear forward! Well done!